# how to know viewForAnnotation is no more being called?

Tags: iphone, ios4, mkmapview

I'm wondering...how to know that that method is no more being called?

method:

```
mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation 
{
}
```

How to know the above method is no more called?

*<sup>(From the comments:)</sup>*
I have a method add location which calculates le coordinates from an array of coordinates and places them on the map, then the `mapView:(MKMapView *) mapView viewForAnnotation:(id ) annotation { }` is being called to place the different custom image instead of the pins...

this takes around 30 seconds....

meanwhile I have started to animate an activity indicator so as the user does not think that the app has crashed....

I want to stop the activity indicator when it has finished...

Comment: I have a method add location which calculates le coordinates from an array of coordinates and places them on the map, then the mapView:(MKMapView *) mapView viewForAnnotation:(id ) annotation { } is being called to place the different custom image instead of the pins... this takes around 30 seconds....meanwhile I have started to animate an activity indicator so as the user does not think that the app has crashed....I want to stop the activity indicator when it has finished...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `didAddAnnotationViews` delegate method to tell when the annotation views have been displayed on the map and stop the activity indicator there:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views
{
    [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
}
```

But you may want to look into whether it's possible to reduce the time it takes to add the annotations in the first place since 30 seconds is a long time.  Maybe you could only add the annotations that would be visible in the current region.